# Get value of an array without using the key name

Tags: php, arrays

I am having the following array:

```
$products = array(
    'B004X6ABTM' => array(
        'price' => '44.96',
        'priceOld' => '59.22',
        'percentageSaved' => 24,
        'currency' => '$',
        'currencyCode' => 'USD'
    )
);
```

The key `B004X6ABTM` is different from product to product. However, I would like to have a general solution to get the `price` and `currency` for every product.

How can I reference the first value of an array, without using the name of the key.

I tried the following, which does not give me any output:

```
echo $products[0];
```

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: You can convert `associative` array to `index` array by `array_keys` function of php. Then you can access it by `echo $products[0]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

From the documentation: That will set the internal pointer of an array to its first element and returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is empty.

```
$value = reset($products);
echo $value["currency"];
echo $value["price"];
```

That would give you:

> $44.96

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/foMUZ)

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below:

```
$keys = array_keys( $products);
print_r($products[ $keys[0] ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). It will remove keys from array.

```
$products = array_values($products);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get price and currency of all product wise,

```
foreach ($products as $prod_code => $row) {
   echo "Price= ".$row['price']." & Currency=".$row['currency']."<br>";
}
```